# function Hover in and out

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousehover

I'm trying to add a mouse in and out on the following code:

```
$(function() {
  var HasTooltip = $('.hastooltip');
  HasTooltip.on('hover', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var isShowing = $(this).data('isShowing');
    HasTooltip.removeData('isShowing');
    if (isShowing !== 'true') {
      HasTooltip.not(this).tooltip('hide');
      $(this).data('isShowing', "true");
      $(this).tooltip('show');

    }

    /*else
    {
     $(this).tooltip('hide');
    }*/

  }).tooltip({
    animation: true,
    trigger: 'manual'
  });
});
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Its a script on a CMS, so may refer to other document.

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried, what works, what doesn't work, what is the desired result, .... ?

Comment: As my name-related & fellow-country programmer mentioned above: what do you want to achieve? We need to see more code, html etc. We can't really help you with what you're giving us

Comment: You want to hide and show this tooltip right?

Comment: Many thanks for your responses.  Sorry could I post a link to the site on here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

> .hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )

```
$(function(){
  var HasTooltip = $('.hastooltip');
  HasTooltip.hover(function(e){
    $(this).tooltip('show');
  }, function(){
    $(this).tooltip('hide');
  }).tooltip({
    animation: true,
    trigger: 'manual'
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try

Comment: Thats excellent, I've been trying various combination for hours and couldn't get it to work, really appreciate it.

Comment: Having some issues with the reset button allocated to that column, there are three columns, middle has the main image, the right has a number of option buttons, one is a customise button which opens up the left column, exposing further options. I'd like to have the tooltip highlight when hovering over each option, this is related to a php with:   <a href="#" class="hastooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Select <?php echo $option['name']; ?> option"><?php echo $option['name']; ?></a>  so it picks up the name in the cms.

Comment: [link] (http://costinlondon.com/site/index.php?route=product/product&path=61_63&product_id=78)

Comment: Tell me the in website reference

Comment: (http://costinlondon.com/site/index.php?route=product/product&path=61_63&product_id=78)

Comment: i've opened the page what to do next or tell me what is the issue;

Comment: the left column tooltips appear all together when the reset button, click customise, then choose from the selection, then reset, then click customise again, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: all tooltips are showing together right? is this is problem?